# Utilize standard visualuzation parameters for ImageCollection in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, visualisation

I've noticed that for many image collections in EE there's a set of properties describing default vizulatization parameters. For example, for Landsat `LANDSAT/LO08/C01/T1_RT` it is:

```
...
visualization_0_bands: B4,B3,B2
visualization_0_max: 30000.0
visualization_0_min: 0.0
visualization_0_name: True Color (432)
visualization_1_bands: B5,B4,B3
visualization_1_max: 30000.0
visualization_1_min: 0.0
visualization_1_name: Near Infrared (543)
visualization_2_bands: B7,B5,B3
visualization_2_max: 30000.0
visualization_2_min: 0.0
visualization_2_name: Shortwave Infrared (753)
...
```

Is there a quick way of applying those? (other then explicitly getting each parameter at a time with `get()`)

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question, I wondered the same thing. I am not aware that there is a pre-built function that accomplishes that.

So for convenience I made a function myself, to retrieve the visualization parameters with the corresponding number as a dictionary from a collection. Here's how it works:

```
function getVis(collection, number){
  var visNumber = ee.String(ee.Number(number))

  var bands = ee.String("visualization_0_bands").replace("0", visNumber)
  var max = ee.String("visualization_0_max").replace("0", visNumber)
  var min = ee.String("visualization_0_min").replace("0", visNumber)

  if(collection.getString(max).getInfo() === null){
    print("Visualisation number "+ number + " is not available,", 
    "or the collection has no visualisation properties.",
    "Pick a number which exists in the properties.",
    "An empty visualization will be returned.")
    return {}
  }

  return ee.Dictionary({
    bands: collection.getString(bands).split(","),
    max: ee.Number.parse(collection.getString(max)),
    min: ee.Number.parse(collection.getString(min))
  }).getInfo()
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LO08/C01/T1_RT")

var visParams = getVis(collection, 1)

Map.addLayer(collection.mosaic(), visParams, "Test")
```

You could save only the function in a script and implement it whenever you need it with `require()`.